# Azure: Using PHP as WebRole and using c# as WorkRole? How to package the service pack?

Tags: c#, php, azure

I'm trying to use PHP as the web role and use C# as the work role. But how to package them together into a service package? I use PHPAzure SDK for php development, which contains a package tool named "package". But it is used for PHP codes. I don't know how to add C# codes and PHP codes together. Also, is it possible using "cspack" command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll look into this over the next week. For now, what yo ucan do is create 2 hosted services, for example:

- myphpapp.cloudapp.net just running your PHP code
- myworker.cloudapp.net which will be a regular C# worker role project